# matplotlib's ion() does not make any difference

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, matplotlib-animation, matplotlib-ion

To test the matplotlib's interactive mode, I used the following two code snippets:

**Snippet 1:** Has `plt.ion()` with no call to `fig.canvas.draw()`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([])
y_1 = np.array([])
y_2 = np.array([])

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)

fig.show()

for i in range(0, 100000):
    x = np.append(x, i)
    y_1 = np.append(y_1, i**2)
    y_2 = np.append(y_2, i**3)

    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    ax1.scatter(x, y_1)
    ax2.scatter(x, y_2)

    #fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.02)
```

**Snippet 2:** Has `plt.ion()` with call to `fig.canvas.draw()`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([])
y_1 = np.array([])
y_2 = np.array([])

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)

fig.show()

for i in range(0, 100000):
    x = np.append(x, i)
    y_1 = np.append(y_1, i**2)
    y_2 = np.append(y_2, i**3)

    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    ax1.scatter(x, y_1)
    ax2.scatter(x, y_2)

    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.02)
```

I could not see any difference between the two plotted figures. Both the figures were updated/redrawn automatically.

Further, I set the interactive mode off using `plt.ioff()` with no call to `fig.canvas.draw()`:

**Snippet 3:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([])
y_1 = np.array([])
y_2 = np.array([])

plt.ioff()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)

fig.show()

for i in range(0, 100000):
    x = np.append(x, i)
    y_1 = np.append(y_1, i**2)
    y_2 = np.append(y_2, i**3)

    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    ax1.scatter(x, y_1)
    ax2.scatter(x, y_2)

    #fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.02)
```

Same behaviour was observed across all the 3 snippets.

According to what is mentioned on https://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg21139.html about `ion()`:

> PS: the documentation I was referring to reads: "The interactive property of
> the pyplot interface controls whether a figure canvas is drawn on every
> pyplot command. If interactive is False, then the figure state is updated on
> every plot command, but will only be drawn on explicit calls to draw(). When
> interactive is True, then every pyplot command triggers a draw."

the expected behaviour of **Snippet 3** should be different than that of **Snippet 1** & **Snippet 2.** For **Snippet 3**, the figure should not get updated/redrawn automatically.

Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?